# AngularJS controller with application don't working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hopes that you guys are fine. I'm recently started to learning AngularJS and it was going good. I'm creating controller and using it in my webpages these are working perfectly. But now I'm at a stage there I'm creating controller with app but it's not working Properly I'm following W3schools and I also copied codes from there but even then too it's not working I just tried a lot of time but I don't getting the problem exactly. So if look it and give me a solution then i will appreciate it.

**Update of this Topic:** Oh Yeah ! I got the Matter.. The problem was I used first a app module on my body tag and that was administrator so I'm trying to use it now on a div under body.. but this tag isn't getting privilege with the tag i used on body so because of it conflicting Now It's clear to me..... I hope it will help many beginners.

Here is those codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 {{ firstName + " " + lastName }}
</div>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at this [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/4h14no0m/2/), pasted exact HTML above and it was working. Are you sure angular library is loading fine?

Comment: Yeah It is loading fine Because I'm still working with angularJS with Directives and and simple controllers

Comment: Make sure other things don't return before the above can execute the script. If you shared the rest of the JS I might be able to help more.

Comment: [Please check the pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/EfF5ZYwr) i shared there my codes and these codes are working perfectly with the linked angular js from local directory

Comment: OK, first you need to separate most of that messy code out. Create controllers for each one and comment out the code. I believe by just declaring functions you are not actually declaring controllers. Start there, paste a better pastebin link. Of course I can go and clean things up and try to figure out what you intended to do, but you need to help us to help you. :) Cheers, I'll be waiting.

Comment: I don't know what is the wrong But there was happening some conflict matters or like that.. When I'm just simply using these codes with my local angular min file it is working properly. But i don't know where is the conflict do happening.   I mean this code is working properly when I'm separting it from my other codes.

Comment: Oh Yeah ! I got the Matter.. The problem was I used first a app module on my body tag and that was administrator so I'm trying to use it now on a div under body.. but this tag isn't getting privilege with the tag i used on body so because of it conflicting Now It's clear to me.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh Yeah ! I got the Matter.. The problem was I used first a app module on my body tag and that was administrator so I'm trying to use it now on a div under body.. but this tag isn't getting privilege with the tag i used on body so because of it conflicting Now It's clear to me..... So if you use any app module on your body then you can't use any other app module on div or anywhere under body so while you need many app module please take care about it. otherwise you will messed your important time also like me. and thanks everyone for helping me.